# Adding line numbers to a multi-line text box

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, line-numbers

I have 2 text boxes in my form, one is for the content (`mainTextBox`), which is on the right, and the other is for the line numbers (`linesTextBox`), which is on the left. Both boxes are the same height and both are multi-line text boxes.

Every time text changes in `mainTextBox` I call the method `writeLineNumbers(mainTextBox.Lines.Count())` which runs a for loop to populate `linesTextBox`. It looks like this:

```
private void mainTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int linecount = mainTextBox.Lines.Count();
    writeLineNumbers(linecount);
}

private void writeLineNumbers(int linecount)
{
    linesTextBox.Text = "";
    int i = 1;
    foreach (var lines in mainTextBox.Lines)
    {
        linesTextBox.AppendText(i + "\n");
        i++;
    }
}
```

This works, however it is extremely taxing and slow on the system once you get past about 50 lines. I've tried a few other things but I cant seem to find a way to do this.

Ive tried this way but its very glitchy and breaks alot but I think Im on the right track

```
private void writeLineNumbers(int count)
{
    int lineBoxCount = linesTextBox.Lines.Count();
    int mainBoxCount = count;

    if (lineBoxCount != mainBoxCount && lineBoxCount > mainBoxCount)
    {
        while (lineBoxCount > mainBoxCount)
        {
            linesTextBox.Text = linesTextBox.Text.Remove(linesTextBox.Text.LastIndexOf(Environment.NewLine));
            lineBoxCount--;
        }
    }
    else if (lineBoxCount != mainBoxCount && lineBoxCount < mainBoxCount)
    {
        while (lineBoxCount < mainBoxCount)
        {
            linesTextBox.AppendText(count + "\n");
            lineBoxCount++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you are effectively trying to build the UI you often see in code editors (having line numbers in front).

I would recommend not try to reinvent the wheel, but use an existing control for this. I often use [ScintillaNET](https://scintillanet.codeplex.com/), which is a .NET wrapper around the common known Scintilla, which is used in Notepad++ for example.

The good news is: you get syntax highlighting for free.

Comment: Your right I am creating my own text editor. I use notepad all the time but I wanted a couple more features so I am creating my own little version. Il check out what you suggested however. Perhaps its a more reasonable solution

Answer (score 0):

WPF o WinForms?

In case of WPF you can always make your custom control with the Textbox inside and make a Label for each line all inside a container like a Grid or a StackPanel.